# quarkus.http.enable-compression in src/main/resources/application.properties ignored since 2.9.0.Final?

Tags: quarkus

I have `quarkus.http.enable-compression=true` in my `src/main/resources/application.properties` file, and with Quarkus 2.8.3.Final it works as expected.  i.e. HTTP requests with an `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header receive a gzip'd response body.

But when I update to Quarkus 2.9.0.Final (or later) `quarkus.http.enable-compression=true` seems to be ignored, and HTTP response bodies are no longer gzip'd.

I see from the Migration Guide 2.9 that "HTTP compression settings have been made build time configuration so they cannot be overridden at runtime anymore."  But my understanding is that application.properties can hold both build time and runtime configuration.

I also tried taking the setting out of application.properties and instead:

```
quarkus:dev -Dquarkus.http.enable-compression=true
```

That works on 2.8.3.Final, but not on 2.9.0.Final.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

yes, the migration guide is incomplete. Previously, all HTTP responses were compressed if the config property `quarkus.http.enable-compression` was set to `true`. Since 2.9 the response body is compressed if `quarkus.http.enable-compression=true` AND:

1. A JAX-RS resource method or a reactive route is annotated with `@io.quarkus.vertx.http.Compressed`, or
2. The `Content-Type` header is set and the value is a compressed media type as configured via [`quarkus.http.compress-media-types`](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-vertx-http_quarkus.http.compress-media-types).

See also:

- https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#http-compression
- https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-routes#http-compression
- https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#http-compression

Comment: I've updated the migration guide: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/wiki/Migration-Guide-2.9#http-compression

Comment: For me with `quarkus.http.enable-compression=true` and with `@Compressed` on the method it still do not return gzipped body for `Accept-Encoding: gzip` request header. Im doing something wrong?

Comment: Ok, somehow after adding and removing `quarkus.http.compression-level` it start working, mb some config was cached, idk.